# How can I show my revenuehits ad when user click on youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

In my WordPress website I am showing a video using following code and I have a revenuehits account to show ad on my website. The advertisement code is something like this :

**advertisement code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//eclkmpbn.com/adServe/banners?tid=84362_136195_5'></script>
```

**Youtube Video code :**

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$post_id =  get_the_id();                 
$youtube_key = get_post_meta( $post_id, "youtube_video_key", false);
$youtube_key =  $youtube_key[0];                      
?>                   

<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $youtube_key; ?>?modestbranding=1&controls=0' width='300' height='175' frameborder='0' ></iframe>

<?php
endwhile;
?>                    
</div>
```

So I want to run this advertisement code when user click on Youtube video. Is it possible, If so then How can I do that ?

Thank You.

Comment: is there a way to embed the ad into a div instead of being generated into the page at the bottom?, I am using this embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 but it is generating an additional iframe onto the page